# how to fetch data from aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently, I start to learn aws and also try to work on it, but there is one query at the time of data fatching from aws to our app.

I follow all the ateps which are mention in aws's suggestion but, steel got error. access deniel so, if any one know about it than please help me.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: I create database in aws ec2 and i want to fetch that data in my android app, so what can i do for that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is unclear and it is not easy to understand what you are seeking. Please Edit your question and provide more details about what services you are using, what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far (including example code) and what errors problems you are experiencing. That way, we will better be able to answer your question.